# Web.Config Rewrite URL with name from the mysql database

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, web-config

I have a Web.config file that I use to rewrite the url in an amicable way as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>

                // rewrites here
                <rule name="articles" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/?$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/article.asp?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But I need to show instead the mywebsite.com/article/1/ the name of the article that is in the database for example mywebsite.com/title-article/.
I already did a good research but I did not find anything that really explained how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with web.config, because web.config can't query the database.  All you could do is create a separate rewrite rule for each individual page in your articles table.

Your other option, and the option which was used a lot more before the advent of the IIS URL rewrite module is to create a custom 404 page and put the logic in that page.

In the system.webServer section of your config file add the following:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

On your 404 page, you can retrieve the url which took the user to the page with

```
Request.ServerVariables("query_string")
```

and then you can use VBScript to get the part of the URL you want and use it in a Database query.  With the Url pattern in your example I'd suggest

```
Dim TitleArticle
TitleArticle = Replace(Request.ServerVariables("query_string"),"404;http://mywebsite.com/","")
```

You could then use `TitleArticle` in a database query to find the page you want, and `Server.Transfer` to take the user there, while preserving the friendly url in the address bar.  I recommend using `Response.Write TitleArticle` while you're testing to make sure you're sending the right value to the database.

Obviously this would all need to be within conditional statements, and the `Else` condition would be to display the standard 404 message